# Troubles reading a text file using Python and sorting into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

I am having issues reading a text file into Python, i am using a loop and it keeps stopping before the end of the text file as well as skipping the first line of the file, i'm sorting it into a dictionary as i read each line.My code is:

```
for x in file.readline():
    s=file.readline().rstrip()
    s=s.split(': ')
    if s[0]=='RootObject':
        Root=s[1]
    if s[0]=='Object':
        data[s[1]]={}
        Ob=s[1]
    elif s[0]=='Satellites':
        data[Ob][s[0]]=s[1]
    elif s[0]=='Orbital Radius':
        data[Ob][s[0]]=float(s[1])
    elif s[0]=='Period':
        data[Ob][s[0]]=float(s[1])
    elif s[0]=='Radius':
        data[Ob][s[0]]=float(s[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to iterate over `file.readline()` like that.  You should iterate over the lines instead like this:

```
with open('/your/file.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    s = line.rstrip().split(': ')
    # etc
```